# Turning a UV layout into an image?

Tags: uv, image, uv-image-editor

I want to be able to print out my UV layout, so as to be able to assemble the model out of paper (or wood, if I lasercut). Is there an easy way to turn the edges in the UV editor into outlines on the image, so I can see where to cut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can export your UV layout as an image.
Open up the UV editor and...

[image]